# Python split panda dataframe based on whether the value in column satisfy a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to split the panda data frame into 2 based on whether the value in a column satisfies a condition, I can do this if it is just a normal condition.

```
df1 = df[df['relevant'] == 1]
```

However, if I do,

```
df1 = df[earlier_or_later(df['timestamp']) == True]
```

It doesn't work. `Earlier_or_later` is a function I wrote which returns whether the timestamp str in each 'timestamp' column is earlier or later than a threshold.

It seems like `'Series'`  object is passed into the function instead of each individual value in column 'timestamp'.

How to accomplish this?

Comment: `df[df['timestamp'].apply(earlier_or_later)]`?

Comment: If your threshold is a fixed date, you can use something like `df[df['timestamp'] < '2020-01-01']`. If not, please explain how `Earlier_or_later` choose that threshold

Comment: @HenryEcker, thanks, it works now.